# How pass json from angularjs to d3?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, d3.js

in my application controller I make a request to my api. It looks like this :

```
.state('state1', {
      url: '/datas/:id',
      templateUrl: 'myurl.com',
      title: 'title',
            controller: function($http, $rootScope, $location,  $stateParams){
              var id = $stateParams.id;               
        $http.post('http://' + $location.host() + id, {id: id } , {})
        .then(function(d){

          $rootScope.data = d.data;
        },
        function(err){
          console.log(err);
        });
      },
    })
```

my d3 script is something like this :

```html
<script>
  ...
   var force = d3.layout.force().size([width, height]).on("tick", tick);

   var svg = d3.select("#d3g").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
   var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
        node = svg.selectAll(".node");
  ...
  ...
  d3.json("data.json", function(error, json) {
              if (error){
                console.log(error);
              } 
    ...
    ...
</script>
```

How can I pass data I receive from api (in the `controller`) to my d3 display (in and html file).

Comment: Well you don't need to do d3.json since you have already done the Ajax in the controller , so you will need to move the code inside d3.json success block into the then function of the promise

Comment: @Cyril thank, now how to i have access to data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More "angular way" is loadind data in a service and creating a directive to render your d3 component like:

```
.service('dataLoader', function($http, $location,  $stateParams){
    return {
        get: function() {
            var id = $stateParams.id;               
            return $http
                .post('http://' + $location.host() + id, {id: id } , {})
                .then(function(d){
                    return d.data;
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                  return err;
                });
            }
    }
})

.directive('mapElement', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E'
    scope: {},
    controller: function(dataLoader) {
       ...
       var force = d3.layout.force().size([width, height]).on("tick", tick);

       var svg = d3.select("#d3g").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
       var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
            node = svg.selectAll(".node");
      ...
      ...
      dataLoader
        .get()
        .then(function(data){
            d3.json(data, function(error, json) {
                  if (error){
                    console.log(error);
                  } 
                ...
                ...
            }
        })
  } 
});
```

To usage this directive, just put in your html:

```
<map-element></map-element>
```